# Non-blocking assignment to ref parameter

Tags: system-verilog

I would like to understand how tasks in System Verilog work. I thought that a task was just a way of naming and parametrising a bit of code that could otherwise appear enclosed between a `begin` and an `end`. However, the way that the parameters work is non-obvious.

Say I want to factor out instances of non-blocking assignments from a module. I might do something like the following, thus reaching the point where there are two instances of the same task that differ just in the parameters (ff_0 and ff_1).

```
module test_inlined;

bit clk;
int count = 0;   
logic [7:0] x, y, z;

task automatic ff_0;
   @(posedge clk);
   y <= x;
endtask

task automatic ff_1; // really same task as ff_0 to within variable renaming
   @(posedge clk);
   z <= y;
endtask   

always
  ff_0;

always
  ff_1;

always @(posedge clk)
  $strobe("%d: x=%d, y=%d, z=%d", count, x, y, z);

always
  #5 clk = !clk;

always @(posedge clk)
  begin
    x <= count;
    count ++;
    if (count > 20) $finish;    
  end   

endmodule
```

It would be trivial to instead place the factored out assignments (aka flip-flops) into two instantiations of the same module, so it would make sense for it to be also possible to express the same functionality in terms of two instances of the same task.

The following does not work because `out` is supposedly automatic, or that is what Modelsim claims. I do not see why it would be since it is fairly obviously a reference to a static member of a module?

```
task automatic ff (ref logic [7:0] out, ref logic [7:0] inp, ref bit clk);
 @(posedge clk);
 out <= inp;
endtask   

module test_broken;

  bit clk;
  int count = 0;   
  logic [7:0] x, y, z;

  always
    ff(y, x, clk);

  always
    ff(z, y, clk);

  // .... same as before

endmodule
```

It does make sense that the tasks need to be automatic to use ref parameters because then there is no need to worry about their lifetime. It is less clear why only blocking assignments to an automatic variable would be allowed. It is not like there is any obvious need for auto variables to go away while there are pending non-blocking assignments?

How do I factor out non-blocking assignments into a task, please? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the purpose of using tasks in your case? factoring out non-blocking assignments is a way to make the rtl non-readable, and using tasks  is the way to make it non-synthesizable.  Are you building a test bench this way?

Comment: It is just a way of  making the question as simple as possible. What I really want to do is build a testbench that understands an abstract representation of the testvectors. If I had to use a buzzword, it would be TLP.  Neither side of the testbench should need a module, especially as they would both need to take arguments by reference and would not be synthesisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `task` cannot assume anything about the storage classification of the variable passed to it. The code generated for the task has to work for any kind of storage, so passing by `ref` has to take on the pessimistic set of restrictions.

Comment: I am not sure how true that is. There clearly are implementation options that would not have that requirement, such as inlining. Also, it is unclear just why it is such huge a problem to have a non-blocking assignment to an automatic variable. In any case, many thanks for your answer.

Comment: In-lining virtual methods of a class based testbench is not feasible.

Comment: The lifetime of an automatic variable is tied to the lifetime the procedural block(scope) where the variable is defined. It's easy to check the references to a variable at compile time to make sure they are within the scope of the block.  An NBA could schedule an assignment to a variable after its life has ended, and the reference is no longer valid. Although SV could devise a way to extend the life a variable when there are scheduled assignment, that would place a tremendous runtime burden to figure that out.